# What are these mystery references in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

Some of my project's references that were obtained via NuGet appear with a blue logo:

[image]

What are these objects? Why can't I see any properties for them, or view them in Object Browser? Ultimately I want to discover the types that these objects contain, for example, in the Rx-Testing item above, since there seems to be no documentation for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are not assembly references. They are references to NuGet packages. Each NuGet package can contain multiple assemblies. You can use the NuGet package manager to view more details on these.

Also, from the [NuGet documentation](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-dialog), you can find the assembly files on the local disk under a folder named packages created in your solution folder.

Comment: This might be true for a "normal" VS solution, but not for a UWP 10 solution. There is no "packages" folder anywhere in my solution disk folder. It looks like all packages for all solutions are stored in C:\Users\[username]\.nuget\packages. And still no way to browse the types or assemblies inside a nuget package item

Comment: What you see under the %userprofile%\.nuget\packages folder is a local copy of the NuGet packages, as mentioned [here](http://blog.nuget.org/20150729/Introducing-nuget-uwp.html). If you have retrieved the source code from elsewhere (downloaded it, or from a source control repository), you might not see the assemblies from these NuGet packages under the solution folder, as you might not have installed/restored these NuGet packages into the solution. To do that, issue the nuget restore command from the [command line](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/command-line-reference).